# How to declare a match pattern in Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

In my Java application I try to read a text file and add to a hashmap some groups of string only. I'm using a match pattern to find the string but I don't get the correct string. My text file content is

```
S Fr:                                     tod : 80089789
kid#00332001897678    cno :  890768
cuon          #PKGS             WEIGHT 
51235
```

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(tod:[0-9]{0,}|kid#[0-9]{0,})|Cno:[0-9]{0,}|CUON  [0-9]{0,}");
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  strLine= strLine.trim();
  Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(strLine);
  while (m1.find()) 
    allv.add(m1.group());
```

Comment: The expression in the code doesn't match the file at all because of differences in white space and letter case. Are these examples real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is that regular expressions require you to specifically indicate if there's going to be white space. For example

`tod : 80089789`

is not matched by the regex

`tod:[0-9]{0,}`

but it is matched by the regex

`tod : [0-9]{0,}`

or the more general

`tod\s*:\s*[0-9]{0,}`

`\s` meaning 'a whitespace character' and `*` meaning 'do the previous thing 0 or more times'. In fact, you can replace all your `{0,}` with `*` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute your code on your file I receive 1 match.  So if that's not what you want... please clarify your question.

See img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS130.png

Comment: i want to add all matches in arryList..tod,kid,con,cuon